# Custom Field type was empty in views

Tags: views, 7, entities

Im build a module, and this module was add a new field type, and all its good, but when i try to use this field in view, its print empty.. no value.., but when I use delta field, its retrieve value ..

look here: 
[image]

how i can integrate field value with view ..?

this code I used for create field ..

```
// Install New type of field module.install
function custom_anees_location_field_schema($field) {
  $schema = array();
  $schema['columns']['option'] = array(
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 25,
      'not null' => FALSE
  );
  return $schema;
}
 // mymodule.module
function custom_anees_location_field_info() {
  return array(
    'country_list_location' => array(
      'label' => t('Country Location'),
      'description' => t('Field For spesfic Location content'),
      'settings' => array('max_length' => 255),
      'instance_settings' => array(
        'text_processing' => 0,
      ),
      'default_widget' => 'options_select',
      'default_formatter' => 'states_field_options',
    ),
  );
}

function custom_anees_location_field_widget_info_alter(&$info) {
  $widgets = array(
    'options_select' => array('country_list_location'),
  );
  foreach ($widgets as $widget => $field_types) {
    $info[$widget]['field types'] = array_merge($info[$widget]['field types'], $field_types);
  }
}

function custom_anees_location_element_validate($element, &$form_state) {
  switch ($element['#type']) {
    case 'textfield':
      if ($element['#value'] == '') {
        form_error($element, t('Case Name may not be blank.'));
      }
      break;
    case 'checkboxes':
      if (empty($element['#value'])) {
        form_error($element, t('You must give at least one role access to this state.'));
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to let Views know about your custom field in database with `hook_views_data`. Here is an article that explains all about it: http://blog.menhir.be/2008/10/22/expose-database-fields-to-views-in-a-custom-drupal-module/

Comment: Im using it, And im create inc file, handler .. also not work

to i can skip this problem now, Im found this

function custom_anees_location_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $element = array(); // Initialize the var
  
  foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      $element[] = "#".$item['option'];
  }

  return $element;
}